# Add content to JQuery node set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML string that I convert to a JQuery node set:

```
var html = "<div id='foo'><div id='bar'></div></div>";
var nodes = $(html);
```

I want to add the content `<div id="baz"></div>` immediately after `<div id='bar'></div>`. I tried using:

```
nodes.find('#bar').prepend('<div id="baz"></div>');
```

But this yields the result:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">
    <div id="baz"></div>
  </div>
</div
```

But what I want is:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <div id="baz"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: from the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/): *Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, **to the beginning** of each element in the **set of matched elements**.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nodes.append('<div id="baz"></div>');
```

or...

```
$('<div>',{id:"baz"}).appendTo(nodes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try after

```
nodes.find('#bar').after('<div id="baz"></div>');
```

Here is the sample : http://jsfiddle.net/UCghk/3/